# autofac more than one concrete class using the same interface

Tags: inversion-of-control, autofac

Question on autofac IOC.

My application has MANY concrete classes implementing the same interface.  How do I register these in startup, and then resolve them in my controllers?

For example, i just have one IRepository interface for CRUD operations to database, but numerous concrete classes that implement IRepository.

Comment: is the intent to resolve all the implementing classes in your controller, or just one of them?

Comment: One based on the need.  I could have an interface called 'ILogger' and concrete classes call 'TextLogger' and 'EmailLogger'.  I may want to use one/the other/both depending on the scenario.

Comment: Autofac has a capability where you can register with a name you can use that ... see the link below...http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#named-services

Comment: You may be running into this: http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html